# Ajax request does not update database until page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm making a ToDo list for a dashboard system I'm creating.
[image: View ToDo List]

So the idea is that a user can add new ToDo items, delete ToDo items and finish/unfinish ToDo items. I'm working in this project with codeIgniter.

The problem is when I'm adding a task it is added to the database but when I delete it after that or finish it, it has not been updated in the database. Only when I refresh the page and delete the task or finish the task after that it is  updated in the database. I have checked the data and that has been succesfuly sended to the controller and from the controller to the model. It just does not get updated in the Database for some reason.

I'm sending all data using AJAX post requests to the codeigniter controller.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
runBind();
function runBind() {

    /**
     * Deletes a task in the To Do list
     */
    $('.destroy').on('click', function (e) {
        var $currentListItem = $(this).closest('li');
        var $currentListItemLabel = $currentListItem.find('label');
        $('#main-content').trigger('heightChange');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'dashboard/deleteToDo',
            type: 'post',
            data: 'message=' + $currentListItemLabel.text()
        }).success(function (data) {
            $currentListItem.remove();
        }).error(function () {
            alert("Error deleting this item. This item was not deleted, please try again.");
        })
    });

    /**
     * Finish the to do task or unfinish it depending on the data attribute.
     */
    $('.toggle').on('ifClicked', function (e) {
        console.log("hallo");
        var $currentListItemLabel = $(this).closest('li').find('label');
        /*
         * Do this or add css and remove JS dynamic css.
         */
        if ($currentListItemLabel.attr('data') == 'done') {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dashboard/finishToDo',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'message=' + $currentListItemLabel.text() + '&finish=' + false
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $currentListItemLabel.attr('data', '');
                $currentListItemLabel.css('text-decoration', 'none');
            }).error(function () {
                alert("Error updating this item. This item was not updated, please try again.");
            })
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'dashboard/finishToDo',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'message=' + $currentListItemLabel.text() + '&finish=' + true
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $currentListItemLabel.attr('data', 'done');
                $currentListItemLabel.css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
            }).error(function () {
                alert("Error updating this item. This item was not updated, please try again.");
            })
        }
    });
}

$todoList = $('#todo-list');

/**
 * Add a new To Do task.
 */
$("#frm_toDo").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');

    var method = $(this).attr('method');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data
    }).success(function (data) {
        addItemToHTMLList();
        $('#new-todo').val('');
    }).error(function () {
        alert("Error saving this task. This task has not been saved, please try again.");
    });
});

/**
 * Adds the task that has been created directly to the HTML page
 */
var addItemToHTMLList = function () {
    $('.destroy').off('click');
    $('.toggle').off('click');
    var todos = "";
    todos +=
        "<li>" +
        "<div class='view'>" +
            "<div class='row'>" +
                "<div class='col-xs-1'>" +
                    "<input class='toggle' type='checkbox'>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='col-xs-10'>" +
                    "<label id='item'>" + " " + $('#new-todo').val() + "</label>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='col-xs-1'>" +
                    "<a class='destroy'></a>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</li>" + $todoList.html();
    $todoList.html(todos);
    $todoList.find('input').iCheck({checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-grey', radioClass: 'iradio_flat-grey'});
    runBind();
    $('#main').show();
}
});
```

It would be great if you can help me out because I have no clue. I have checked all the data but it just does not get updated in the database before the page refresh.

Comment: Have you compared the XHR requests using browser dev tools to ensure they are 100% equivalent (for a delete on an existing todo versus a delete on a newly added todo)? Also, the typical pattern is to use some sort of id instead of using the whole message as the matcher -- have you considered having finish/delete operate on the id of the todo instead of sending the text of the todo? You can make a unique id if you do not want to expose your database ids.

Comment: Hey @Cymen, Thanks for your answer. I have compared the two SQL queries it executes when deleting a Task. It seems all newly created tasks are not yet trimmed which happens in the validate method when reloading the page. So all messages began with a nasty space. Problem is fixed now. I will change the message to an unique ID as sending the whole message is indeed a bit dirty.

Comment: Excellent! I added my comment as an answer if you want to accept. I didn't feel there was enough detail to give an answer but apparently it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you compared the XHR requests using browser dev tools to ensure they are 100% equivalent (for a delete on an existing todo versus a delete on a newly added todo)?

Also, the typical pattern is to use some sort of id instead of using the whole message as the matcher -- have you considered having finish/delete operate on the id of the todo instead of sending the text of the todo? You can make a unique id if you do not want to expose your database ids.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating objects after the page has finished initializing and the events have already been attached. You need to instead assign the events to a parent element, so that this element delegates the event to any new items in the to-do. See the "Delegated Events" section in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hello @skertchly, Thank you for your answer. This was not the problem. See my comment on Cymen. I rerun the rebind function after I have created a new Task so this should be no problem.